# Unable to get invoices from Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I've never dealt with Stripe before so could you please suggest what could be wrong.

In one of the projects we have a bug so user is unable to change amount of items in subscription. I've ran through logs and found an exception from Stripe client:

```
StripeException: No upcoming invoices for customer: cus_xxxxx
```

This error only appeares at production environment and I can't reproduce it on dev so I guess the issue is on the Stripe's side. What can cause it?

Comment: The most likely case is that the customer does not have any active Subscriptions.